# Playground execution failed: error: Couldn't lookup symbols - Playground in xcode using swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I just started using playground and trying to run some basic code to start with, for instance:

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"
```

I guess it's supposed to run in real-time but it takes forever to run in my case and after some time, I get the following error:

```
Playground execution failed: error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreGraphics
__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftUIKit
__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDarwin
__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreImage
__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFoundation
__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftObjectiveC
_playground_log_hidden
__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDispatch
_playground_logger_initialize
_playground_log_postprint


thread #1: tid = 0x39745, 0x00000001006283c0 MyPlayground2`executePlayground, 
queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.2
  * frame #0: 0x00000001006283c0 MyPlayground2`executePlayground
frame #1: 0x00000001006279c0 MyPlayground2`__37-[XCPAppDelegate 
enqueueRunLoopBlock]_block_invoke + 32
frame #2: 0x000000010114225c 
CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
frame #3: 0x0000000101127304 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 356
frame #4: 0x0000000101126a75 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 901
frame #5: 0x0000000101126494 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
frame #6: 0x0000000106531a6f GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
frame #7: 0x0000000101cd0f34 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
frame #8: 0x00000001006276e9 MyPlayground2`main + 201
frame #9: 0x000000010467e68d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Comment: please post the code that is not running too :)

Comment: It's the basic code ever. Check the description :) @Fluidity

Comment: playgrounds is glitchy. Honestly. Reboot your mac, start a new playground. haha. or try a different version of xcode. i can never get playground to work consistently